# How to save picture in memory (not in internal storage)

Tags: android

Please Look at the codes below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
```

This code is for calling camera function. 
After I take a picture, the method onActivityResult gives me back Uri so that I can get the absolute path to internal storage of the picture. But, I want to use the picture just for temporary use. that is, I don't want the picture to be stored in internal storage. I need absolute path to make the picture into a File object. So, is there any way to store the picture on memory allocated to my app??

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA){

        imageUri = data.getData();
        Log.d("메시지", "uri = "+imageUri);


        Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToNext();
        absolutePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use Cache Directory:

```
File storagePath = new File(getCacheDir() + "/" + "YOUR_FILE_NAME.JPG");
```

Comment: The picture is stored in gallery as soon as I take a picture...I want to stop it..